# Range.SpecialCells: What does xlCellTypeBlanks actually represent?

Tags: vba, excel

The [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel) can be used to return a Range object meeting certain criteria. The type of criteria is specified using an xlCellType constant.

One of those constants (xlCellTypeBlanks) is described as referring to "Empty cells" with [no further elaboration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlcelltype-enumeration-excel).

Does anyone know what definition of "Empty" this method uses? Does it include cells with no values/formulas but various other features (data validation, normal formatting, conditional formatting, etc)?

Comment: I'd say Empty means not even a null string. 
 See this code sample http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.co.uk/2018/04/vba-use-pivottable-and.html

Answer (score 4):

That type includes the subset of cells in a range that contain neither constants nor formulas.  Say starting with an empty sheet we put something in **A1** and **A10** and then run:

```
Sub ExtraSpecial()
Set r = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
MsgBox r.Count
End Sub
```

we get:

[image]

Formatting and Comments are not included.  Also note that all the "empty" cells below **A10** are also ignored.

Comment: Weird. If you *only* add the value to A1, you get an exception. If you add values to A1 + A10 then delete the value in A10, the count is 9. It looks like it's defining its range to search in the same way SpecialCells calculates its "Last Cell" using xlCellTypeLastCell. Which is itself different from the way that Sheet.UsedRange calculates; in my "Add something to A10, then delete it" example, ws.UsedRange.Address returns "A1", but ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address returns "A10".

Comment: @DanielMcCracken That is because `UsedRange` is not re-calculated.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too soon. See my updated comment: UsedRange *is* recalculated, it's using some other kind of method to find its range to search.

Answer (score 2):

The definition does indeed contain the idea of having nothing in the cell, i.e. it excludes any cell that contains either:

- a numerical value
- a date or time value
- a text string (even an empty one)
- a formula (even if returning an empty string)
- an error
- a boolean value

But it also ***excludes any cell that’s not within the range going from A1 to the last used cell of the sheet*** (which can be identified programmatically through `ws.cells.specialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)`, or by using the keyboard `Ctrl+End`).

So if the sheet contains data down to cell C10 (i.e. `Ctrl+End` brings the focus to cell C10), then running `Range("D:D").specialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` will fail.

<sub>**NB** The range `A1 to LastCellUsed` can sometimes be different from the `used range`. That would happen if some rows at the top and/or some columns at on the left never contained any data.</sub>

---

On the other hand, cells that fit the empty definition above will be properly identified no matter any of the followings:

- size or colour of font
- background colour or pattern
- conditional formatting
- borders
- comments
- or any previous existence of these that would later have been cleared.

---

A bit beside the main subject, let me ask a tricky question related to how the term **BLANK** might be defined within Excel:

- *How can a cell return the same value for `CountA` and `CountBlank`?*

Well, if a cell contains `'` (which will be displayed as a blank cell), both `CountA` and `CountBlank` will return the value 1 when applied to that cell. My guess is that technically, it does contain something, though it is displayed as a blank cell. This strange feature has been discussed [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/counta-and-countblank-of-one-cell-is-1-true/1a234b59-a490-46ed-a0a5-5ce4bbba0bcd).

```
Sub ZeroLengthString()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Range("A2").Value = ""
    ws.Range("A3").Value = Replace("a", "a", "")
    ws.Range("A4").Value = """"
    ws.Range("A6").Value = "'"
    ws.Range("A7").Formula= "=if(1=2/2,"","")"
    ws.Range("B1").Value = "CountA"
    ws.Range("C1").Value = "CountBlank"
    ws.Range("B2:B7").FormulaR1C1 = "=CountA(RC[-1])"
    ws.Range("C2:C7").FormulaR1C1 = "=CountBlank(RC[-2])"

    For i = 2 To 7
        Debug.Print "CountA(A" & i & ") = " & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A" & i))
        Debug.Print "CountBlank(A" & i & ") = " & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ws.Range("A" & i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

In this example, both lines 6 & 7 will return 1 for both CountA and CountBlank.

So the term **Blank** doesn’t appear to be defined a unique way within Excel: it varies from tool to tool.

Comment: I added an answer expanding on the "last used cell" thing, the way Excel calculates it is incredibly bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

Papalew's response noted that "xlCellTypeBlanks" excludes any cells not within a specific version of the "used range" that's calculated in the same way as the special cell type "xlCellTypeLastCell". Through testing I've discovered that "xlCellTypeLastCell" returns the last cell of the "UsedRange" property *as of the last time the property was calculated*.

In other words, adding a line that references "UsedRange" will actually change the behavior of the SpecialCells methods. This is such unusual/unexpected behavior that I figured I'd add an answer documenting it.

```
Sub lastCellExample()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets.Add
    ws.Range("A1").Value = "x"
    ws.Range("A5").Value = "x"
    ws.Range("A10").Value = "x"

    'Initially the "UsedRange" and calculated used range are identical
    Debug.Print ws.UsedRange.Address
    '$A$1:$A$10

    Debug.Print ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), _
                ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Address
    '$A$1:$A$10

    Debug.Print ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
    '$A$2:$A$4,$A$6:$A$9


    'After deleting a value, "UsedRange" is recalculated, but the last cell is not...
    ws.Range("A10").Clear
    Debug.Print ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), _
                ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Address
    '$A$1:$A$10

    Debug.Print ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
    '$A$2:$A$4,$A$6:$A$10

    Debug.Print ws.UsedRange.Address
    '$A$1:$A$5


    '...until you try again after referencing "UsedRange"
    Debug.Print ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), _
                ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Address
    '$A$1:$A$5

    Debug.Print ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
    '$A$2:$A$4

End Sub
```