# How to Write Excel Macro to Delete Entire Row if cell Value Equals ""

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have a macro that deletes an entire row of the cell value equals "" for multiple ranges.  Ranges are "B16:B115, B131:B230, B250:B349".

Logic: 
If cell equals "" then delete the entire row.

I want the row actually deleted and not just the contents of the cells.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the "related" questions on this page - (over to the right).  See if any of those give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be worth trying:

```
On Error Resume Next
Range("B16:B115,B131:B230,B250:B349").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error Goto 0
```

Depending on whether the "" cells have formulas or are just empty.
[Range.SpecialCells: What does xlCellTypeBlanks actually represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49924308/range-specialcells-what-does-xlcelltypeblanks-actually-represent)

EDIT: if you have formulas then you have to go the long way round:

```
Sub DeleteEmpty()

    Dim c As Range, rngDel As Range

    For Each c In Range("B16:B115,B131:B230,B250:B349").Cells
        If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
            If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = c
            Else
                Set rngDel = Application.Union(rngDel, c)
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly without anything in the cells.  Thank you for that.  But I actually do have a formula in the cells.

The formula is as follows "=IF('Receiving Import'!C2="", "", 'Receiving Import'!C2)" with C2 incrementally by 1 for each row.  If the value is true then it returns "".  Those are the cells I would like the row deleted for. This is why it has become tricky for me and I need help figuring out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Following sub will allow you to select range to delete blank rows.

```
Sub RemoveBlanks()
Dim rng As Range, rws As Long, i As Long
Dim LastRow As Range
Dim myRange As Range

  Set myRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select Header Cell To Remove Blanks.", Type:=8)
  'LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Set LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, myRange.Column).End(xlUp)
  Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(myRange.Address & ":" & LastRow.Address)
  rws = rng.Rows.Count

  For i = rws To 1 Step (-1)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(i)) = 0 Then rng.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
  Next

  Set myRange = Nothing
  Set LastRow = Nothing
  Set rng = Nothing

End Sub
```